# DataAdapter Raises a concurrency violation exception when using UpdateBatchSize

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using DataAdapter and I update my data very well with no problem but when I use the UpdateBatchSize Property I got an Exception : "Concurrency violation: the batched command affected 0 of the expected 2 records."???
The Code Below is part of my DAL

```
myAdapter.InsertCommand = InsertCmd();
myAdapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = System.Data.UpdateRowSource.None;
myAdapter.DeleteCommand = DeleteCmd();
myAdapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = System.Data.UpdateRowSource.None;
myAdapter.UpdateCommand = UpdateCmd();
myAdapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = System.Data.UpdateRowSource.None;

myAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = myConnection.conn;
myAdapter.InsertCommand.Connection = myConnection.conn;
myAdapter.UpdateCommand.Connection = myConnection.conn;
myAdapter.DeleteCommand.Connection = myConnection.conn;

myAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = false;
myAdapter.UpdateBatchSize = 2;

try
{
    myAdapter.Update(dt.GetChanges());
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I got after searching , that ,you can't use Adapter UpdateBatchSize Property with the optimitstic concurrency provided with your SQL Command ,The Command will Fail due to the size of timestamp column or concurrency check for each column ,so the SQL Command will be very large  ,so you can't get everything.

IF you want to use UpdateBatchSize to minimize the server travels you got to get rid of timestamp column check in your sqlcommand or the concurrency option provided in your SqlAdapter